# Objective-C: Creating NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

For my iPhone app, I want to manage values either in `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableAarray`.

I want to store rating in this format

```
round   player1  player2
  1        6        8
  2        7        9
--        --        --
```

Here in my case number of round will be fix value suppose 10, and total player would be 2 that is also fix.

But user can submit their score in any random order but in single button click. Means

```
 score for round  "10" for both the player   enter
 score for round  "2"  for both the player   enter
```

How can I manage dictionary or array which could help me in retrieving them again easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//You can use combination of mutable array and dictionary to handle each round and player score

NSMutableArray *mutArrayRound=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];


//--EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------

//You need to do it somewhere so that it'll not give error for [mutArrayRound insertObject: atIndex:]

mutDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    [mutArrayRound addObject:mutDic];
}

[mutDic release];

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

NSMutableDictionary *mutDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
[mutDic setValue:@"Score_Valaue" forKey:@"player1-Score"];
[mutDic setValue:@"Score_Valaue" forKey:@"player2-Score"];

//For Round1
[mutArrayRound insertObject:mutDic atIndex:0];

//For Round2
[mutArrayRound insertObject:mutDic atIndex:1];


/*
    You can access for particular round using mutDic=[mutArrayRound objectAtIndex:0];
    And to access player score, you can use key score=[mutDic valueForKey:@"Player1_Score"];
 */

[mutArrayRound release];
[mutDic release];
```

Comment: hey if i want to add like [mutArrayRound insertObject:mutDic atIndex:1]; first and  [mutArrayRound insertObject:mutDic atIndex:0];  means not in sequence then how to manage

Comment: For different rounds you can pass round-1 as index for array like `[mutArrayRound insertObject:mutDic atIndex:round-1];` As you've specified your round is between 1 to 10.

Comment: thanks for replay but my question is whether it would allow me to insert at objectatIndex:9 first  if there is no any object on indexes from 0 to 8

Comment: ok thanks I tried but somehow it didn't work for me I will try again.

Comment: @ios, I also checked it, Its showing error of beyond index. Okey, let it forget. I want to ask you. In your game, whats the exact flow? I am guessing If user complete first Round, then only go for second Round? and like vise for all remaining rounds? or directly play Round 6 or 8 or 7 etc.?

Comment: @ios, I've solved above problem! I am editing my answer. Sorry for inconvience

Answer (score 4):

Why only arrays or dictionaries in an object-oriented language?

```
@interface RoundResults : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger playerOneScore;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger playerTwoScore;

@end

@interface GameTotal : NSObject

- (void)setResults: (RoundResults *)results forRound: (NSInteger)round;
- (RoundResults *)resultsForRound: (NSInteger)round;
- (NSUInteger)countOfResults;

@end
```

Comment: We have classes and objects in Objective-C, so you're not limited to only the built-in collection types. If you define classes like the ones I've shown you can convey more meaning in your data structures than if you use dictionaries and array. In turn you make code that's easier to understand and change; and you hide the details of how you store these results so you can use different algorithms or storage later.

Answer (score 2):

You can make NSMutableArray of NSDictionary:

```
      NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
                // Now say Player one got 50 and Player2 got 65 in first round then add them in dictionary


                NSDictionary *dict  = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"50",@"P1",@"65",@"P2", nil];
                [arr addObject:dict];
[dict release];


            // As soon as you got the sores make a NSDictionary object and init it with objects like above and add that to the mutable array . It will add it to next index.
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ,here in my case problem is :if user add the score for round 9 first and round 1 afterwords then how to manage

Comment: I think .. for this at first  you can make 10 dicts with "0" score for P1 also and "0" for P2 also. after adding all 10 dicts into mutable array, You can replace the NSDictionary object at particular index whatever user enters for the round number.

Answer (score 1):

**Idea 1 :**

```
NSMutableDictionary* playerArounds = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary* playerBrounds = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[playerArounds setObject:@"5" forKey:@"1"]; 
// Player A scored 5 for round 1

// etc...
```

**Idea 2 :** (suitable if >2 players)

```
NSMutableArray* playerRounds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    [playerRounds addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

[[playerRounds objectAtIndex:0] setObject:@"5" forKey:@"1"];  
// Player 0 scored 5 for round 1

// etc...
```

**Idea 3 :** (a more pure-C approach)

```
// a 2-dimensional array
int scores[2][10]; 

scores[0][2] = 5;

// Player 0's score for round 3 (2+1) is 5
```

---

***As pointed out :***

Instead of e.g. `[playerArounds setObject:@"5" forKey:@"1"];`, since your values will be int (and not strings), you'd better use  (it would make more sense) :

e.g. `[playerArounds setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];`

Comment: Use `setObject:forKey:` to put objects in a dictionary.

Comment: And use NSNumbers for the keys.

Comment: @JeremyP Good point for `setObject:forKey:` (just corrected it). Now as for using e.g. `[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]` instead of `@"5"` is obviously the way the OP would go if he implements it as suggested. I just avoided to do it this way as to make the code more... readable. Good point too, though...